# ios 9 closed caption is always on

Tags: ios, ios9, avplayerlayer, closed-captions

I am using AVPlayer on my app and it seems that closed caption is always on when is on iOS 9 devices.  It doesn't respect the propery - 'closedCaptionDisplayEnabled' at all.  Also I made sure the accessibility closed caption option on the device setting is off as well.

Comment: May I know which player you are using? Is it possibly a third-party player, such as Brightcove, which has AVPlayer underneath or it is purely AVPlayer?